# installation of R package results in an error message

Tags: r, package

I tried to install the R package crypticIBD check but got the follwing error when I tried to use it

```
> library("CrypticIBDcheck")
load package : rJPSGCS
load package : rJava
Error : .onLoad in loadNamespace() für 'rJava' error, details:
  command: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
error: Paket ‘rJava’ can't be found
>
```

coudl somebody point me into a direction?

I then successfully installed the rJava package and treid to run the package again

```
 : .onLoad in loadNamespace() error for rJava
  command: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
error: Paket ‘rJava’ can't be found
>
```

Comment: Try following the install instructions here: http://www.rforge.net/rJava/

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so, either your Java and R architectures don't match or somehow the java.exe was not put in your PATH. If you're on linux, you can just `R  CMD javareconf`. This is a short version of what flodel linked you to. It just so happens I was solving this problem yesterday. :)